# Which available hook after products bulk save is completed in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-wordpress

I have customized the bulk edit functionality using

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start', function () {
    // ...
}, 10, 0);

add_action('woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save', function ($product) {
    // ...
}, 10, 1);
```

I would like to do some further processing after all products have been saved. Is there a hook I can tie into for that?

Any pointers are welcome.

**Clarification:** I do need to access all information sent in the bulk edit request (bulk edit field values, product ids, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Wordpress `admin_init` action hook like in this example, where a custom message is displayed after products have been saved:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'after_bulk_edit_products_save' );
function after_bulk_edit_products_save() {
    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow === 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'product'
    && isset($_GET['paged']) && ( isset($_GET['updated']) || isset($_GET['skipped']) || isset($_GET['locked']) ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'custom_bulk_action_admin_notice' );
    }
}

function custom_bulk_action_admin_notice() {
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated"><p>This is a custom message displayed after save</p></div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> **You can access from `$_GET` the following variables** *(always use `isset()` to avoid errors)*:
>
> - `$_GET['post_type']` - the post type which is "product"
> - `$_GET['paged']` - default value is "1" most
> - `$_GET['updated'`] - the number of products "updated"
> - `$_GET['skipped']` - the number of products "skipped"
> - `$_GET['locked']` - the number of products "locked"

#### Note:

> You have access to all the data submitted for bulk edit *(and quick edit)* in the `$_REQUEST` global.

Comment: This looks like it might just work, I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone coming to this down the road: you have access to all the things submitted for bulk edit in the `$_REQUEST` global. :)

Comment: @mike.bronner Yes of course! I will add it as a note.